# Chamar resultado de foreach laravel de controller e mostrar na view

Tags: php, mysql, controller, laravel-5.6

Preciso recuperar um método no controller e exibir na view,

```
Controller
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Categoria;
use App\Models\Sessoes;
class todosProdutosController extends Controller{
public function categorias(){

    $categorias = Categoria::where('nome', 'LIKE', '%a%')->get();
    foreach ($categorias as $categoria) {
        $categoriaNome = $categoria->nome;
        $sessao = $categoria->sessoes; // posso adicionar condições
        foreach ($sessao as $sessao_) {
            $sessao_->nome;
        }
return view('home.home', 'produto', $categoriaNome);
    }
}}
```

E na minha view esta assim

```
<section id="produtos">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            {{ dd($categoriaNome) }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Alguma ajuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Controller
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Categoria;
use App\Models\Sessoes;
class todosProdutosController extends Controller{
public function categorias(){

    $categorias = Categoria::where('nome', 'LIKE', '%a%')->get();
    return view('home.home', compact('categorias'));
}}
```

E sua view Fica assim:

```
<section id="produtos">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @foreach($categorias as $categoria)
                {{$categoria->nome}}
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nas tags `foreach` você não precisa adicionar as chaves "{{"

Comment: @Luigi Jordânio continua me retornando erro >> Undefined variable: categorias (View: F:\xampp\htdocs\estudo\resources\views\home\home.blade.php) onde posso estar errando?

Comment: Encontrei o problema,é que ele tinha um argumento a mais, ficando assim: return view('home.home',  compact('categorias')); Muito obrigado pela ajuda =)